# PHP json_encode returns null to d3.json call

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, d3.js

Attempting to use d3.json utilizing a json_encode call in a php file. Getting null data from call.

I have the following PHP file called getdata.php:

```
<?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli('database','user','pass');
   $myArray = array();

   $query1="UPDATE ezDB.newsTable SET RADII = FLOOR(RAND()*(1200-100) + 100) #END";
   $mysqli->query("$query1");

   $query2="UPDATE ezDB.newsTable SET RADII = FLOOR(RAND()*((minRadii+500)-(minRadii-500)) + (minRadii-500))";
   $mysqli->query("$query2");

   if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT indexKey, radii, source, headline, siteurl, dateAdded, storyAge FROM ezDB.newsTable")) {
   
       while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
               $myArray[] = $row;
       }
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
       echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
   }
   
   $result->close();
   $mysqli->close();
```

The php file has been tested with xampp and outputs the following json formatted data:

```
[{"indexKey":1,"radii":176,"source":"real","headline":"testHead","siteurl":"testURL","dateAdded":"2023-01-02","storyAge":0},{"indexKey":7,"radii":212,"source":"real","headline":"testHead","siteurl":"testURL","dateAdded":"2023-01-02","storyAge":0},{"indexKey":8,"radii":434,"source":"real","headline":"testHead","siteurl":"testURL","dateAdded":"2023-01-02","storyAge":0},{"indexKey":9,"radii":333,"source":"real","headline":"testHead","siteurl":"testURL","dateAdded":"2023-01-02","storyAge":0},{"indexKey":112,"radii":602,"source":"real","headline":"testHead","siteurl":"testURL","dateAdded":"2023-01-02","storyAge":0}]
```

I have copy and pasted this PHP output into a separate test.json file and tested the d3.json command, it worked perfectly so I know the formatting is fine.

In my html index file I use the following code:

```
d3.json("getdata.php", function(data) {
                    console.log("TESTING PHP JSON:");
                    console.log(data);
 }
```

When using vsCode Live Server and Firefox to debug, I can see that the console returns the following:

TESTING PHP JSON:
null

Additionally the debugger raises the following flag in d3.v4.js:
Paused on exception
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

On this line of code:

```
var json = type$1("application/json", function(xhr) {
  return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Have seen a number of issues similar, but I'm at a loss here. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
Screenshot of Network tools view.

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure that your vscode live server supports PHP? (an extension is required)

Comment: @brombeer Yes I added Live Server's firefox extension which supports PHP. Unfortunately no luck.

Comment: "_PHP file called getData.php_" vs `getdata.php` Is the name correct? Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see requests/responses and their payload

Comment: "unexpected character" suggests the response contains something else. Check the Network tool to examine the response fully.

Comment: @ADyson Couldn't that unexpected character just be the lack of one, or a null response?

Comment: As @brombeer suggested: Check the network tab of DevTools in Firefox to see what the actual request and response look like.

Comment: You may have a UTF-8 BOM at the beginning.

Comment: @Olivier I do have a "<meta charset="utf-8" />" in my index.html. Is that an issue?

Comment: No, check in your text editor if getdata.php has a BOM.

Comment: @Olivier It does not. I pasted in my entire php file in the post.

Comment: *"I pasted in my entire php file in the post"* So? That doesn't prove that your file has no BOM.

Comment: A way to check is to load your script on [hexed.it](https://hexed.it/). If the file begins with `EF BB BF`, then you have a BOM.

Comment: Thanks didn't know how to check. According to hexed I do not have a BOM.

Comment: Then you should use the DevTools, as already suggested.

Comment: @Connor `Couldn't that unexpected character just be the lack of one, or a null response`...I'd expect it to say "unexpected end of response" or something like that, in that scenario. More likely there's something like a PHP error or similar, in the AJAX response.

Comment: Unfortunately my Network Dev Tools experience and knowledge is very limited. I posted a screenshot of my network page. My inexperienced eye can't find anything.

Comment: PHP is not interpreted!

Comment: So you wrote this whole script but never checked that your PHP setup was actually working?

Comment: The PHP is working, I can see the updates happening in my server. Apologies, the original screenshot I posted was looking at a debugging call. I have updated the image to what it actually looks like, original code as described in the post.

Comment: @Olivier I'm not sure how you would infer from that screenshot that PHP is not being interpreted? We can't see the Response tab, and there's nothing else to suggest it

Comment: @ADyson See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbdcD.png)

Comment: The request tab has "No payload for this request". The response tab displays the full php file.

Comment: @Connor so you're saying that if you click the "Response" tab for that request to getdata.php that you've shown in the screenshot, that it shows you actual raw PHP code? If that's the case, then it _does_ very much indicate that the PHP code is not being executed. Are you running this code on a webserver which actually supports PHP? It sounds like you aren't.

Comment: port 5500 is an unusual port for a "standard" server to run on. How about you ditch that live server and use Apache instead, where the result seems to be the correct JSON?

Comment: @ADyson It does indeed. I suppose my configuration is wrong somehow then? I have all my site files in a subfolder within "C:\xampp\htdocs". I then open index.html using live server in vscode. I have also tested this code within an AWS EC2 Instances(PHP enabled) and I get the same results as I do when testing locally.

Comment: `I then open index.html using live server in vscode`...that isn't a server which supports PHP. It only supports really basic static sites. If you've got XAMPP installed, serve your pages through the Apache server which came with that instead (it's probably running on the default port 80, rather than 5500). (P.S. I think there's a plugin possibly which can make VS Code liveserver work with PHP, you can google it, it takes a bit of setting up though, and overall you'll likely get an experience closer to most deployed environments if you use Apache)

Comment: And there we go, that was it for testing locally. I was NOT using xampp properly and was conflating it with live server. The solution for local testing was ensuring ALL site(not just php) files were in the xampp/htdocs folder and then pasting the path in my browser. http://localhost/websiteV1/index.html. Big thanks to all of you. Now to ensure this works on my AWS instance....